# Why was "что ты думаешь" deemed incorrect?

Tags: грамматика, выражения

I mostly use the following for *"What do you think?"*

> как ты думаешь?

I understand there can be many variants of the aforementioned question, and I have seen a few of them. I was recently following a thread on Reddit and somebody was called out for using

> что ты думаешь?

Maybe its the artless state of my Russian, but I cant understand why that would be incorrect? Does it not mean the same or at least something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Что ты думаешь... ?** is an *unfinished* or *incomplete* question. Its complete form is something like **Что ты *об этом* думаешь... ?** or **Что ты думаешь по этому поводу** *(на этот счёт, об этом)*? Some words **must** be included in the **question itself**, while the question **Как ты думаешь?** does **not** need that. However, it still needs a previous context, typically a more detailed question, so **Как ты думаешь?** is about someone's personal opinion on the subject and it much better corresponds to the mentioned English version.

Answer (score 2):

Both these questions are normal in Russian, but there is a difference in usage.

The question with **что** is used when you ask to express an opinion about something. You introduce the subject with **о** preposition or with words like **насчёт**, **по поводу**:

*Что ты думаешь о глобальном потеплении?* -  What do you think about global warming?

The question with **как** is used when you ask to make a choice of something (including questions you can answer with yes/no). There is no preposition:

*Как ты думаешь, завтра будет дождь или нет?* -  What do you think, will it rain tomorrow or not?

Notable that use of **что** was normal in this case a hundred years ago or so.

When you just said something and want your interlocutor to reply in some way, both questions will work:

*[А] как ты думаешь?* (more usual, less formal)

*[А] что ты думаешь?*

If in doubt, opt for **что**. In the worst case you will sound old-fashioned.

Answer (score 0):

Simple "what do you think?" should be translated as "что думаешь?" or "как думаешь?", but the context should be clear.

If it's "what do you think [about something]?", than it should be translated like other guys already said.